# How to get remote notifications count

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to ask if there is a way to get remote notifications count when launching the app.

I can do it by checking the `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber` value or checking `[@"aps"][@"badge"]` value of `userInfo` dictionary in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UITabar` increase the `badge count` of that particular tab when ever you get the notification and you can decrease it the particular action done by user. Even you can get the no.of active unread notifications also by reading the badge count of that `tabbar` item.

Comment: I'm not using the UITabbar. I just wanna know all the possibilities to get the total count of remote notifications.

Comment: Have a count in NSUserDefaults and when ever you get a notification the control will come to `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` so in this method you can increase the notification count.